# Reference .sql file(s) saved on TFS in SSIS

Tags: sql, tfs, ssis

I am working as part of a wider team, on an SSIS package. We use TFS for collaboration, and the package has links to .sql files amongst other things.

When I run the package manually, the package runs without any issues, as the connection manager references my directory. When someone else tries to execute the package, they get an error message "Could not find a part of the path ......... script.sql"

Is there a way to correctly reference the TFS location, so it works for everyone, or is there some other way to reference these files in SSIS, so they work for everyone in the team?

Thank you

Comment: Is your package set up to reference SQL files? I don't recommend this approach. I recommend actually putting the SQL code inside the database and managing it with a database project.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for this. I had already thought about this as a viable option, but was keen to see if there were other options

Comment: If you have the opportunity to change, change now. If you want to stick with what you have then I guess you need to work out exactly what the problem is - for example compare the path in the package to the real path. You must be just about the only team doing it this way - it's not recommended.